# Trying to filter and combine JSON items

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework

I have a JSON with several objects with this format:

```
[{
  "id":14,
  "friendlyName":"NameOfPlace 1",
  "lat":30.402735,
  "lon":-90,
  "address":"1 place street",
  "city":"NYC",
  "state":"NY",
  "zipCode":"12346",
  "locationCode":"MQ00003",
  "details":"in the bank"
},
{
  "id":15,
  "friendlyName":"NameOfPlace 2",
  "lat":30.402735,
  "lon":-90,
  "address":"1 place street",
  "city":"NYC",
  "state":"NY",
  "zipCode":"12346",
  "locationCode":"MQ00003",
  "details":"near ATM"
}]
```

They are locations of stores. I have several of these in a list. Some of them have names like Name 1 and Name 2, if there are 2 locations within the same building. I am trying to find a way to combine them into one object with both values but only one place ("Name" in the case of the example). I have two questions, if I have list of objects like above can I sort based off of `friendlyName` alphabetically then check to see if there are similar named locations that can be combined into one object. Note the locations will have the same lat long and address, just different details and ids. I can only figure out how todo it linearly and it is very slow for the mobile app I am trying to do.

Comment: use `underscore.js` you can do it all.

Comment: You definitely can use underscore.js.  Not at all necessary though.  Simply use the `sort` method.

Comment: The sorting was fairly easy I figured. What about the checking. The locations would always end in a number. My immediate though is to check for an integer at the end, and the search the next few in the list and see if they have the same string value up until the integer spot and then take their details and add it to the first object.

Comment: do you have some more data to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I added the formatting, but basically I have several different objects like above. and Some of them have the same name with a different integer to differentiate which location it is within the same building

Comment: what should happen with different properties, like `details`?

Comment: they should concatenate, so it would be `details 1, details 2` essentially and the id should be just taken as the first one, ie if there is 14 and 15 just take 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the grouping of the friendly name and generate a new array with the data. If the data is different, all values are in an array included.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 14, "friendlyName": "NameOfPlace 1", "lat": 30.402735, "lon": -90, "address": "1 place street", "city": "NYC", "state": "NY", "zipCode": "12346", "locationCode": "MQ00003", "details": "in the bank" }, { "id": 15, "friendlyName": "NameOfPlace 2", "lat": 30.402735, "lon": -90, "address": "1 place street", "city": "NYC", "state": "NY", "zipCode": "12346", "locationCode": "MQ00003", "details": "near ATM" }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = o.friendlyName.split(/(?= \d*$)/)[0];
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = { Name: key };
        grouped.push(this[key]);
    }
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (!(k in this[key])) {
            this[key][k] = o[k];
            return;
        }
        if (this[key][k] === o[k]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(this[key][k])) {
            this[key][k].push(o[k]);
            return;
        }
        this[key][k] = [this[key][k], o[k]];
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: so it works but how would you make it so it just has one id value, not an array? I need to use the id value for accessing views. Just defaulting it to the smaller value would be easiest

Comment: you can perform a `Array#join(', ')` on it and get all ids separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

> can I sort based off of friendlyName alphabetically

You can do it by using [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

```
var sortedArray = json.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.friendlyName>b.friendlyName?1:-1
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o3ns2eho/)